# why do I get "Attempted to unregister unknown __weak variable" when copying an instance variable?

Tags: swift, weak-references, nscopying

I noticed this today when playing with NSOutlineView and NSTableHeaderCell, but when this specific configuration is made, an error/warning(?) is printed:

**objc[2774]: Attempted to unregister unknown __weak variable at 0x1016070d0. This is probably incorrect use of objc_storeWeak() and objc_loadWeak(). Break on objc_weak_error to debug.**

here's the snippet:

```
class Foo: NSCell {
    weak var weak: NSView?

    override func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        // according to NSCopying documentation:
        // If a subclass inherits NSCopying from its superclass and declares
        // additional instance variables, the subclass has to override copy(with:)
        // to properly handle its own instance variables, invoking the superclass’s implementation first.
        let copy = super.copy(with: zone) as! Foo

        // this produces "Attempted to unregister unknown __weak variable"
        copy.weak = self.weak

        return copy
    }
}

let view = NSView(frame: NSRect.zero)

let foo = Foo()
foo.weak = view

let copy = foo.copy() as! Foo
```

this also happens if I substitute NSCell with: NSEvent, NSImage, NSImageCell

but this doesn't happen to NSColor, NSDate, NSIndexPath

I started learning Swift without prior knowledge of Obj-C. could someone help me understand why this is? is it safe to ignore? who has the blame in this case?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, also with `NSCell`. I think that something's up with it. Using a strong variable instead of a weak variable seems to eventually cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

This is a framework bug. It's easy to reproduce with the following crasher:

```
import Cocoa

class Cell: NSCell {
    var contents: NSString?

    override func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let newObject = super.copy(with: zone) as! Cell
        newObject.contents = contents
        return newObject
    }
}

func crash() {
    let cell = Cell()
    cell.contents = "hello world"
    cell.copy() // crashes while releasing the copied object
}

crash()
```

When you use a `weak` var instead, you get the error message that you showed.

My gut feeling is that there is something in the `copy` implementation of `NSCell` (and possibly of `NSEvent` and `NSImage`) that does not handle subclassing for types that have non-trivial constructors. Accordingly, if you change `let newObject = super.copy(...)` with `let newObject = Cell()`, the crash is avoided. If your superclass's copy logic is simple enough, you should probably do that for now.

If you hit this problem, you should file a bug report separately of mine, but you can probably reuse my sample.