# NSTableView with NSTableHeaderCell subclass with delegate property crash

Tags: swift, macos

**The issue:**

When a custom delegate property is populated in a NSTableHeaderCell subclass, the code crashes to the App Delegate @Main. Using App Testing Address Sanitizer reveals this error

> NSTableView Custom Header Cell(17503,0x11071e600) malloc: nano zone
> abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.

**The goal:**

The end result is to have a simple NSTableView with two columns where I would like a control in the header of column 1 to have a delegate that's called when an action occurs in that control. Not the header itself, but a custom control added to the header (a checkbox).

**Testing:**

For this post, I removed all other code (checkbox, overrides etc) and narrowed it down to just a NSTableHeaderCell subclass with a single property for the delegate. The delegate code and the ViewController code for the NSTableView

Here's the delegate protocol with a function, and the the CheckboxTableViewHeader subclass with a property to hold the delegate

```
protocol CheckboxDelegate: AnyObject {
    func checkboxClicked() -> Void
}

class CheckboxTableViewHeader : NSTableHeaderCell {
    var myDelegate: CheckboxDelegate?
}
```

and in the viewcontroller the only code is this

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, CheckboxDelegate {
.
.
.
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let firstCol = self.myTableView.tableColumns[0]
    self.myTableView.removeTableColumn(firstCol)

    let col0 = NSTableColumn(identifier: col0Id)
    col0.title = "col 0"
    let col1 = NSTableColumn(identifier: col1Id)
    col1.title = "col 1"
    self.myTableView.addTableColumn(col0)
    self.myTableView.addTableColumn(col1)

    let header = CheckboxTableViewHeader(textCell: "Col 1")

    header.myDelegate = self  // <-- this will cause a crash, but not here..
                              // ..crash occurs after viewDidLoad concludes

    self.myTableView.tableColumns[1].headerCell = header

    self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    self.myTableView.delegate = self
}

//
//MARK: - the custom header delegate
//
func checkboxClicked() {
    print(#function)
}
```

The code above removes the first table column (it has 1 col in IB to start with) and then adds col 0 and col 1 in code, then attempts to set the myDelegate var in the subclass.

The line indicated in the above code `header.myDelegate = self` will cause the app to crash out to @main in the AppDelegate. If that line is removed, it works correctly.

Note that I tried adding another type of var to the subclass `var test: Int` and if that property is set in the viewDidLoad `header.test = 1` instead of setting the delegate, it also works correctly, no crash.

```
macOS: 12.6.3
XCode: 14.2
```

Comment: See [why do I get "Attempted to unregister unknown __weak variable" when copying an instance variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886306/why-do-i-get-attempted-to-unregister-unknown-weak-variable-when-copying-an-i)

Comment: Thanks @Willeke. That was right on point. Had to work with it for a minute. Adding `override func copy(with zone` to the subclass, changing to `var myDelegate: CheckboxDelegate?` and then within that func, `let newObject = Cell()` instead of `let newObject = super.copy(with: zone) as! Cell` worked. Since the error I encountered is different (and quite vague), having an accepted answer here would probably be advantageous to future readers. Can you post some code as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: A `delegate` property is usually weak so I changed it and got the other error. I didn't try the answer. If you have a working solution then post an answer please.

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment, based on the [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886306/why-do-i-get-attempted-to-unregister-unknown-weak-variable-when-copying-an-i) referenced in the comments (which is a different error), the addition of this function override

```
override func copy(with zone
```

appears to be working and the code no longer crashes to @main

```
class CheckboxTableViewHeader: NSTableHeaderCell {

    var buttonDelegate: CheckboxDelegate?

    override func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = CheckboxTableViewHeader(textCell: self.stringValue)
        copy.buttonDelegate = buttonDelegate

        return copy
     }
}
```

Note the error still appears in the log

> malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved
> vm space.

It doesn't appear to be affecting the app but if you want to get rid of that message, in XCode go to the Product menu->Schema->Edit Schema. Then in the Run section, Arguments tab add an Environment Variable "MallocNanoZone" and set it's value to 0

[image]

The caveat is: this may affect the app in unexpected ways so use with caution.